# Can someone recommend a good book that can explain chinese characters and how they came to have their meaning

Tags: meaning

My mind is so literal that I think it would help me to understand  and memorize the characters and their meaning. I recently found on this site an explanation for the difference between sun and speech. It included pictograms and explanations.  With all that detail I will never forget it.

I am perhaps intermediate level.  I studied intensely in college for two semesters before heading to Beijing where I lived for a year. That was in the late 90's.  Unfortunately I haven't had the time to use it or study it since.  Now that I am quarantined I can go back to this language that I love to learn.

I just want some help learning. Some tools to help me remember.

Comment: Are you able to clarify your level?  When students first start learning Chinese, teachers often tell them 人 = person, 山 = mountain, etc., and students interpret this as meaning characters often resemble their meaning.  The student quickly discovers this is not true in general, and instead [phonetic components](https://www.hackingchinese.com/phonetic-components-part-1-the-key-to-80-of-all-chinese-characters/) [which merely indicate how the character is pronounced] are more important.

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Chinese-Writing-Early-Special-Monograph/dp/1557290717

Comment: I studied for two semesters in college in 1996.  In 1997 I lived in Beijing for a year and continued my studies.  I am currently in refresh mode after a long time of inactivity.  So I would put myself at an early intermediate level.  My oral is much better than my written.

Answer (score 3):

this one talked about the early chinese characters from ancient inscription, in english:

[early chinese writing, by frank herring chalfont](https://archive.org/details/earlychinesewrit01chal/page/n3/mode/2up)

though it was printed in 1906, imo, the info is precise & correct; most important, it’s a **free** download, provided you’re not in “you-know-where”

[image]

Comment: Spotted one mistake :) 虫 = 虺, not 蟲

Comment: omg  well, may i say this one is good enough for foreign-beginner? 

Comment: @dROOOze What books would you recommend? It would be great if you were willing to write a reply. :)

Comment: Seems like a good book even for Chinese people.

Answer (score 0):

"The Chinese language, Its History and Current Usage" by Daniel Kane.

Published by Tuttle Publishing.

Comment: Would it be possible to explain why you're recommending this book please?

Comment: Because I've read it some time ago and it has helped me to have a better understanding of the language, its history and current usage, even though I already have a good working knowledge of the language.